# Eliminar alguns elementos de uma lista e concatenar atributos

Tags: java

Boa tarde, eu possuo uma lista de `Pessoa` onde a classe é assim:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private String idade;

}
```

Montei a lista assim:

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Douglas","30"));
pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Leonardo","30"));
pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Douglas","35"));
```

A lista possui 3 elementos, eu preciso pegar os elementos cujo o atributo `idade` esteja repetindo, apagar um dos elementos e no campo `nome` vou concatenar com vírgula o `nome` do elemento excluído ficando assim:

```
[Pessoa{nome='Douglas,Leonardo', idade='30'}, Pessoa{nome='Douglas', idade='35'}]
```

É possível fazer com uma única instrução lambda?

Comment: Não é possível fazer com uma única função lambda pois é uma tarefa de duas etapas: 1-classificar os dados em um [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) para assim conhecer os elementos repetidos. 2 - Organizar os elementos classificados na estrutura de dados desejada. Serão necessárias duas funções anônimas ao menos.